# Failed to install ghostscript, during Imagemagick installation

Tags: macos, leopard, macports

I'm kinda new to those CLI installations so I don't know exactly what I'm doing I'm just following the installation steps of the guide:

I want to install Imagemagick on my Mac 10.5.8:

I typed ´sudo port install imagemagick´ and I got this error in return:

```
localhost:~ giorgio$ sudo port install imagemagick
--->  Computing dependencies for imagemagick
--->  Dependencies to be installed: ghostscript liblzma urw-fonts webp
--->  Building ghostscript
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install ghostscript
Log for ghostscript is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_print_ghostscript/ghostscript/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: ghostscript liblzma urw-fonts webp
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

I've also tried to look inside the main.log file, but I couldn't understand anything with my knowledges! 
I've pasted it here with the hope that you can help me:
http://pastebin.com/YeAGJQkF

Thanks in advance!
Giorgio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> :debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.

It seems from the error log that you aren't running as root even though you used `sudo`. You need to make sure you're in an admin account then use `sudo port install imagemagick`.